# linq weekly grouping?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Linq

```
from c in customerReadings
group c by new { date = GetGroupingDateKey(DateRangeType, c.ReadDate), name = c.Name } into g
select new MeterReadingsForChart
{
    ReadDate = g.Key.date,
    Name = g.Key.name,
    Value = g.Sum(y => y.Value),
    TimeInterval = DateRangeType
};
```

GetGroupingDateKey()

```
private static DateTime GetGroupingDateKey(MeterReadingsTimeIntervals DateRangeType, DateTime Date)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    switch (DateRangeType)
    {
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Hourly:
            //For Example data is betweet 10:05 - 11:05
            //DateTime offSet = Date.AddMinutes(-5);
            //date = new DateTime(offSet.Year, offSet.Month, offSet.Day, offSet.Hour, 5, 0);
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, Date.Day, Date.Hour, 0, 0);
            break;
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Daily:
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, Date.Day, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Weekly:
            date = Date.AddDays(-((7 + Date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday) % 7));
            break;
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Monthly:
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Yearly:
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
    }

    return date;
}
```

Records time : 10/10/2012 - between 09:15 and 10:15

```
Hourly groupped data count  : 2 (expected)

Daily groupped data count   : 1 (expected)

Weekly groupped data count  : 5 (group count (not expected))

Monthly groupped data count : 1 (expected)

Yearly groupped data count  : 1 (expexted)
```

How can I group records by week. What is the wrong about my weekly grouping?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine your `Date` has a time part - you need to zero it out, e.g.

```
date = Date.Date.AddDays(-((7 + Date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday) % 7));
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought. You always create new `DateTime` values with an empty time part - except for this one case.

Comment: Basically, your original code was transforming e.g. "5pm Tuesday", "7am Friday", "9pm Sunday" to "5pm Monday", "7am Monday", "9pm Monday", so they were all still different. By using `Date.Date` instead of `Date`, this code turns e.g. "5pm Tuesday" to "midnight Tuesday", which is then translated to "midnight Monday".